# Delete singly-linked list with struct elements

Tags: c, recursion, singly-linked-list

I currently am stuck with a task on my current assignment and I have no clue, why it does what it does, instead of what I want.

First of all, here's the assignment:

> Provided is a singly linked list, which is defined as:
>
> ```
> typedef struct { 
>     char lastname[30]; 
>     char firstname[30]; 
> } person_t;
> typedef struct perslistelement { 
>     person_t pers_obj; 
>     struct perslistelement *next; } PersListElement;
> ```
>
> a) Write a function void printPerson(person_t pers) to display an
>   object person_t.
>
> b) Write a function void
>   printPersList(PersListElement *p) which displays every person within
>   the list. Use the function printPerson()
>
> c) Write a recursive function
>   void printReversePersList(PersListElement *p), which displays every
>   saved person in reverse order. I.e. the person which was saved last
>   should be displayed first, etc.. Use the function printPerson()
>
> d) Write a function void deletePersList(PersListElement *p) which deletes
>   a list.
>
> e) Test your functions with the following program:
>
> ```
> #include<stdio.h>
> #include<stdlib.h>
> #include<string.h>
>
> typedef struct {
>     char lastname[30];
>     char firstname[30];
> } person_t;
>
> typedef struct perslistelement {
>     person_t pers_obj;
>     struct perslistelement *next;
> } PersListElement;
>
> PersListElement *insertPerson(PersListElement *first, char lastname[], char firstname[]){
>
>     PersListElement *p;
>     p = (PersListElement*)malloc(sizeof(PersListElement));
>     strcpy(p->pers_obj.lastname, lastname);
>     strcpy(p->pers_obj.firstname, firstname);
>     p->next = first;
>     first = p;
>     return first;
>
> }
>
>
> /* Insert functions from a ) , b ) , c ) and d) ! */
>
>
> int main(void){
>
>     PersListElement *p = NULL;
>     printf("Test Program : Assignment 8 / Task 1");
>
>     printf(" Step 1: Building the list \n" );
>     p = insertPerson(p, "Banner", "Bruce");
>     p = insertPerson(p, "Stark", "Tony");
>
>     printf("\nStep 2: Printing the list\n");
>     printPersList(p);
>
>     printf("\nStep 3: Printing the list in reverse order\n");
>     printReversePersList(p);
>
>     printf("\nStep 4: Deleting the list\n");
>     deletePersList(p);
>
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

I didn't have any issues with assignment a to c. The functions I've written work perfectly fine and do what they should. However, for some reason the last function, where I'm supposed to delete the list only deletes the lastname part of the list elements. At least, when I use the printPersList function after using the delete function it displays the lastnames as mumbo-jumbo, while the firstnames are still intact.

This is what it looks like:

[See attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFY43.png)

Here are the functions I've written:

a)

```
void printPerson(person_t pers){

    printf("Last Name: %s \nFirst Name: %s\n\n", pers.lastname,pers.firstname);

}
```

b)

```
void printPersList(PersListElement *p){

    while(p != NULL) {
        printPerson(p->pers_obj);
        p = p->next;
    }
}
```

c)

```
void printReversePersList(PersListElement *p){

    if (p == NULL) return;
    printReversePersList(p->next);
    printPerson(p->pers_obj);
}
```

d)

```
void deletePersList(PersListElement *p){

    while(p != NULL) {
        free(p);
        p = p->next;
    }
}
```

Can someone please explain to me, what the mistake was and how to solve it?

Also, please keep in mind that I translated this whole assignment from German to English just for stackoverflow, so if there are some other mistakes anywhere outside of the deletePersList function, ignore that please, as it's probably something I just overlooked while translating everything.

Answer (score 2):

You're freeing `p` and then using `p`, which is undefined behavior. You need to get `p->next` and store it in a temp variable or something *before* you free `p`

```
void deletePersList(PersListElement *p){

    while(p != NULL) {
        free(p);
        p = p->next; // this is undefined
    }
}
```

A solution might be

```
void deletePersList(PersListElement *p){
    while(p != NULL) {
        PersListElement *next = p->next;
        free(p);
        p = next; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... I also tried that, but for some reason it still outputs

"Last Name: )╣
First Name: Tony

Last Name: )╣
First Name: Bruce"

Comment: @ArkaineAscorbin you shouldn't be concerned with the output after the delete function. The contents of the memory after free() is undefined, so it's normal to see garbage characters.

Comment: Oh really? I thought I had to delete everything, so there is nothing left after using the delete function. Well, if that's it, the problem most likely is solved then. Thanks for the correction though :)

Comment: Yes, it is solved already. It is somewhat lucky that the program doesn't crash when you try to print the list content after delete, but as you could see, only last name's content get overwritten, the rest remains intact, both first name and the next pointer (that's why you can iterate the list successfully). So if you try to print after delete it may happen to get a segmentation fault.